# Exclamation sign on network bars

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Why do I get bang sign on network bars and WiFi option... Pls tell me what's this all about. Earlier I was using Android KitKat 4.4.4 on moto g2 and I had nonsuch issue there however since I updated to Android lollipop I usually get these bang signs over network bars and WiFi option (if I turn on WiFi)

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that you are currently using cellular data. if using wifi data then bang sign dissappears. a new feature on lollipop

Comment: Appreciate your response dear, i found it appears when v r not connected to either of the two (neither WiFi nor data).... Bt question remains question again, if I am using SHAREIT app from lenovo then the bang sign appears on both WiFi n on network bars.... This is bothering me as I am unable to understand y is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

If its showing exclamatory symbol it means your mobile is loading network or no network on your SIM

Answer (score -2):

It may be the problem in Android or in your network connection.
Make sure you are using Official Android.
It happens mostly in Unofficial Android on Rooted Devices..!